# Getting values of each textbox with the same class inside the table row

Tags: jquery

How to get each value of textbox with the class `timeinhh1` inside the table row?

I'm using this code:

```
function ValidateOnLoad() {
    $('tr').each(function () {
        var timeinhh1 = $(this).children('.timeinhh1').val();
        alert(timeinhh1);
    });
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        // th here
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="timeinhh1" value="9"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="timeinhh2" value="12"></td>
    </tr>        
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="timeinhh1" value="13"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="timeinhh2" value="14"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But it's not working, how to do it correctly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that a mismatch in the class name? `timeinhh1` or `tihhval1`?

Comment: I edited the question sir thanks.

Comment: See it working below.  Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.

your structure is `tr>td>.timeinhh1` so `this.children` gives you `td` not `.timeinhh1`. And `children()` gives you only immediate children of particular element. [Docs](https://api.jquery.com/children/)

try this

```js
 $('tr').each(function() {
   var timeinhh1 = $(this).children('td').children('.timeinhh1  ').val();// using children find td and then timeinhh1 
   var x = $(this).find('.timeinhh1  ').val();// you can do the same using find
   console.log('using chidren - ' + timeinhh1);
   console.log('using find - ' + x)
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>// th here</tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="timeinhh1" value="9" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="timeinhh2" value="12" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="timeinhh1" value="13" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="timeinhh2" value="14" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  ValidateOnLoad();

  function ValidateOnLoad() {
    $('tr').each(function() {
      $(this).find('td').each(function() {
        console.log("td");
        alert($(this).find(".timeinhh1").val());

      });

    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="timeinhh1" value="9">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="timeinhh1" value="13">
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('tr').each(function () {
            var timeinhh1 = $(this).children('td').find('.timeinhh1').val();
            alert(timeinhh1);
        });
    });
```

check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w3suaxnn/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine with little issue that it is not finding .timeinhh1 class on first `tr` thats why it is returning `undefined`, rather than applying each on all tr, apply filter of class which you want i.e `timeinhh1`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr').find('.timeinhh1').each(function () {
            var timeinhh1 = $(this).val();
            alert(timeinhh1);
   
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        // th here
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="timeinhh1" value="9"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="timeinhh2" value="12"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="timeinhh1" value="13"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="timeinhh2" value="14"></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```